# How to infer template parameters from constructors?

Tags: c++, templates

How to infer template parameters from constructors???

```
template<class $sign, signed $size>
class Integer;

template<>
class Integer<signed, 8>
{
public:
    typedef signed long long type;
};

typedef Integer<signed, 8>::type Int64;

template<class $sign, signed $size>
class Integer
{
public:
    Integer(Integer<$sign, $size>::type a){}
    // 1LL(Int64) => Integer<$sign, $size>::type => $sign, $size
    //How to infer <$ sign, $ size>
};

int main() {
    Integer a(1LL);
    return 0;
}
```

How to infer template parameters from constructors???

1LL(Int64) => `Integer<$sign, $size>::type` => $sign, $size

How to infer `<$ sign, $ size>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction as you can see this feature is available only starting C++17.  Although you might have to add another layer of indirection via a traits class or an explicit deduction guide to get your example to work.

If you have a compiler that supports `-std=c++1z` or `-std=gnu++1z` then you can use that as well.

Here is a working example https://wandbox.org/permlink/HqmitAQxSziZx8IC (the same code is pasted below also)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename IntegerType, int width>
class Integer {
public:
    Integer(IntegerType) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
};

template <>
class Integer<signed, 8> {
public:
    Integer(signed) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
};

template <typename IntegerType>
Integer(IntegerType) -> Integer<IntegerType, sizeof(IntegerType)>;

int main() {
    Integer{1LL};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give an example
Thank you